# Caml/Ocaml: pattern matching multiple argument functions

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, caml-light

I'm trying to make this recursive function which takes an `int x` and a list, and then removes the first `x` amount of elements from the list:

```
let rec nthcdr int_t list_t =
  match int_t with
  | 0 -> list_t 
  | _ -> (match list_t with
          | [] -> [] 
          | h::tail -> nthcdr (int_t -1) tail)
  ;;
```

but it does not work, `h::tail` seems to never match, and it always returns `[]`

Comment: Can't reproduce. How are you testing it?

Comment: I agree with @melpomene. You code works for me, so maybe it's your test that is flawed. Here's my test: `nthcdr 3 [1;2;3;4;5]` ==> `int list = [4; 5]`.

Comment: my bad guys! I was testing wrongly.

Comment: It pays to refactor the code so it's more readable (eg. `hd::tl` instead of `h::tail` or `drop n li` instead of whatever the function's name means) before posting or just for your own sanity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to offer improvement to the code as an answer (since OP had already found the solution).

It feels redundant to pattern match an integer `int_t`. You can do it of course, but the benefit of pattern-matching becomes apparent when used with algebraic data types like records or variants or collections like lists. Also, using `if..else` for the integer makes code cleaner and differentiate the base case from the inductive cases.

```
let rec drop n li =
  if n = 0 then li else
  match li with
  | [] -> [] 
  | h::t -> drop (n-1) t
```